# Javascript - Why is my RegEx for dd.mm.yyyy - dd.mm.yyyy not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written following code:

```
var date_regex = new RegExp("\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}", "gi");
var period = "27.03.2014 - 24.04.2014";

console.log(date_regex.exec(period));
```

I get console log : null.

I checked my code on this site and it says valid. What is wrong? Thanks for help!

```
\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo of my RegEx](https://www.debuggex.com/r/R6hvCCWTHugqKnXf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes:

```
var date_regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}[./-]\\d{2}[./-]\\d{4}", "gi");
```

---

Just as a side note, you can avoid matching strings with mismatched delimiters such as "27.01-1444" by capturing the first delimiter and matching the same one for the second delimiter via `\1`:

```
var date_regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}([./-])\\d{2}\\1\\d{4}", "gi");
```

Comment: Thanks to all! I can accept your answer in 11 mins. I was going mad.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating your regex from a string, so you need to escape the backslashes:

```
var date_regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}[./-]\\d{2}[./-]\\d{4}", "gi");
```

Or it's less complicated to use a regex literal:

```
var date_regex = /\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}/gi;
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a regular expression object (as opposed to the literal) with a string, you need to double escape slashes:

```
var date_regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}[./-]\\d{2}[./-]\\d{4}", "gi");
```

You'll discover that logging `date_regex` results in `/d{2}[./-]d{2}[./-]d{4}/gi` - not what we wanted!

However, you only need to use a string under certain conditions:

- The regex involves a variable
- The regex is formed in a loop (string prevents recompilation)

Thus, you'd be better off using a literal in this case:

```
var date_regex = /\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}/gi;
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) for more details on creating RegExp objects.

Comment: Thanks! alot SomeKittens

Comment: @zer02 You're very welcome.  Regexes can be tricky.  Don't forget to upvote and accept!

Answer (score 1):

Combine the given answers and use `.match` to return all matches in an array.

```
var date_regex = /\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}/gi;
var range      = "27.03.2014 - 24.04.2014";

console.log( range.match(date_regex) );  // [ "27.03.2014", "24.04.2014" ]
```

Comment: You don't need the `new RegExp()` part if you're using a regex literal.

Comment: @nnnnnn: true, but for completeness it doesn't hurt

Comment: But it's less efficient (an extra function call that you don't need) and harder to read (because it leaves people wondering why you have an extra function call that you don't need).

Comment: @nnnnnn: more than likely you are right.  I typically use a string and a replace function to double escape backslashes (e.g. `RegExp(re_escape('someregex')`).  In old browsers `typeof /someregex/ === 'function'`, which I never particularly liked, but I'll change the above for performance improvement.